# (Unity - C#) Updating Sprite not working when casting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with setting a new Sprite in my GameObjects SpriteRenderer.

I declare my array like this:

```
public Object[] textures;
```

I use the following code:

```
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, textures.Length);
    Debug.Log("Texture number " + randomIndex + ". Object: " + playerName);
    Sprite texture = textures[randomIndex] as Sprite;
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = texture;
```

When I run my game, the sprite is set to none.

If I change my code to this, I get a runtime error:

```
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, textures.Length);
    Debug.Log("Texture number " + randomIndex + ". Object: " + playerName);
    Sprite texture = (Sprite)textures[randomIndex];
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = texture;
```

Error:

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What objects are stored in "textures" array? Sprites? Have you considered using "Sprite[] sprites"?

Comment: It's images imported in png format. If I change it to Sprite[] sprites I get type mismatch in the inspector

Comment: Ok, so you probably hold them in array as Texture2D instances? If yes, this is the cause of problem. Classes Sprite and Texture2D have different fields and methods so they cannot be used interchangeably as single reference to general / base Object type. You might instantiate some Texture2D objects, add them to array and use them when you want to create new sprite: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no need/use to go through `Object` here.

Either use

```
public Texture2D textures;
```

and as mentioned in the comments above use [`Sprite.Create`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html)

```
int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, textures.Length);
Debug.Log("Texture number " + randomIndex + ". Object: " + playerName);
var texture = textures[randomIndex];
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0,0,texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
```

---

Or simply use a

```
public Sprite textures;
```

and directly do

```
int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, textures.Length);
Debug.Log("Texture number " + randomIndex + ". Object: " + playerName);
var texture = textures[randomIndex];
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = texture;
```

and just make sure in the images's [import settings (Inspector)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html) you set

[Texture Type = `Sprite (2D and UI)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextureTypes.html#Sprite)

[image]