# Singleton script to download images from web download and Malformed URL issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unity-ui

Hi I have written a singleton script called DownloadImage which can be used by any class to download images from web. There is a scene with several images with an attached script WebImage. Webimage internally calls this DownloadImage Singleton to download the image and update its image.
Webimage has url field in which we can pass in the image link.

This system works fine if url is fixed. However if if I change url for ecah image component in scene images are not downloaded properly or I get error saying Malfoemed url. What might be the issue here and how to solve this?

Below is singleton Download script, and this script is attached to empty gameobject component.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DownloadImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static DownloadImage instance;

    [SerializeField] public string url;
    [SerializeField] public Texture2D texture;
    [SerializeField] public bool isCached;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetImageFromWeb(url));
    }

    public IEnumerator GetImageFromWeb(string refURL)
    {
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(refURL);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError || 
            File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "Image.jpg"))
        {
            Debug.Log("-------------------------"  + request.error);

            byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "Image.jpg");
            Texture2D tempText = new Texture2D(60, 90);
            tempText.LoadImage(byteArray);
            texture = tempText;
        }

        else
        {
            texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
            if (isCached)
            {
                SaveDownloadedTexture(texture);
            }
        }
            
    }

    public void SaveDownloadedTexture(Texture2D refTexture)
    {
        bool clearCache;
        byte[] byteArr = refTexture.EncodeToJPG();
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "Image.jpg", byteArr);
        clearCache = Caching.ClearCache();
        if (clearCache)
        {
            Debug.Log("Image deleted");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is script WebImage script which is attache on each of image component in scene that takes url and passes it to singleton.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WebImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public string imageURL;
    [SerializeField] public bool cacheData;

    void Start()
    {
        this.gameObject.AddComponent<RawImage>();
        DownloadImage.instance.url = imageURL;
        DownloadImage.instance.isCached = cacheData;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = DownloadImage.instance.texture;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need your second script? Why does he first need to be a singleton? Why not rather combine both, have one single script which is not anyhow static and rather once you downloaded the image **once** you assign the `RawImage.texture` **once** ... btw `RawImage` in generally is quite expensive .. why not rather use an `Image` an create a proper `Sprite` from your downloaded texture (like e.g. shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66508221/7111561) - different use case but same principle)

Comment: @derHugo it was one of case study for one of my projects. Trying some different approach.

Comment: well the issue with your singleton is: if multiple components overwrite the `DownloadImage.instance.url` .. well then it will download the very last assigned one for all ...

Comment: @derHugo exactly the issue. Any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the comments I made already timing can be a huge issue here!

You are starting the download right away in `DownloadImage.Start`.

But there is no guarantee that your `WebImage.Start` is actually executed before that => maybe the URL is even simply `""`.

Also check your local file path! By simply using `+` what you get is a path like e.g.

```
some/local/filePathImage.jpg
```

what you want would rather be

```
some/local/filePath/Image.jpg
```

So for system paths always use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which inserts the correct path separator depending on the OS the app is running on.

And then you probably would also not want to again and again overwrite the very same local file `Image.jpg` but rather have unique names (for now I will assume based on the last part of the Url)

As said I would simply rather merge these to together into a single component and do something like

```
public class LoadedImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Image image;
    [SerializeField] private string url;
    [SerializeField] private bool isCached;

    // Your path was also invalid!
    // by simply using + you end up with a path like e.g.
    //     some/local/filePathImage.jpg
    // what you rather want is
    //     some/local/filePath/Image.jpg
    // And then still - if you have multiple instancesthey will all overwrite the same local file
    // I would simply use the url again
    private string localPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, url.Split('/').Last());

    // Unity will automatically run this as a Coroutine
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Texture2D texture;

        // First of all why is the local file an error?
        // I would rather expect it to be the default case and only trigger a download
        // if it DOESN'T exist

        // So as first option go for local cached file
        if(File.Exists(localPath))
        {
            byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(localPath);
            texture = new Texture2D(1,1);
            texture.LoadImage(byteArray);
        }
        // as fallback download
        else
        {
            using(var request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(refURL))
            {
                yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            
                if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("-------------------------"  + request.error); 
                    return;
                }
               
                texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;

                if (isCached)
                {
                    SaveDownloadedTexture(texture);
                }
            }
        }   

        if(texture != null)
        {
            // Finally use Image which is way more performant than RawImage which adds DrawCalls to your UI
            image.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
        }
    }

    public void SaveDownloadedTexture(Texture2D refTexture)
    {
        var byteArr = refTexture.EncodeToJPG();
        File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, byteArr);
        var clearCache = Caching.ClearCache();
        if (clearCache)
        {
            Debug.Log("Image deleted");
        }
    }
}
```

There is no need for a singleton. Just have this attached to your image components, configure them and you should be fine.